# Installing New Wall Light Switch with 2 Black and 1 Red Wire to Single Pole

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

Trying to install new switch to turn on a ceiling light.
There are 2 black, 1 red, and ground (bare copper) wire.

How do I wire this to a single pole switch? Or do I need double/3-way switch?
The switch should be the only one to on/off the ceiling light.

[image] [src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PdTw.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Can you post a clearer photo of the back of the box please?

Comment: Any chance it's a combined light/fan fixture? Could be one of those wires is for the fan, one for the light.

Comment: I can't get to the back of the box. The switch should only control one light on/off, that's it. So I was thinking to put both black wires together, red itself and ground is ground

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel OP can't reach the back of the box, but Photoshop can...

Comment: @user146424 the request was for a picture looking _into_ the box so we can visually trace which wire goes into which cable, not to remove the box from the wall or to cut a hole from the other side of the wall...

Answer (score 1):

Depends. If there are 2 switches meant to control this light, that is called "3-way wiring".  Identify the red-black pair that are in the same cable; mark them with yellow tape to indicate they are *travelers* and put them on the brass screws of a 3-way switch.  The black screws gets the solo black wire.

One **generally** should never experiment with hooking up random wires to see what works, because you'd obviously stop at the first combination that works, and many of them will kill you.  However **in this particular case**, all arrangements of red and black wires on a switch should not create a hazardous situation.

Handling the wires and terminals is definitely hazardous; electricity can kill you then!  So shut off the branch circuit or preferably the main breaker before touching any wires.  I do, and I'm really good at this.

---

On the other hand, if this location has 1 switch location, but is a reasonable one to install a *ceiling fan with light*, such installations are typically done with /3 (red black white bare) cable from switch to ceiling.  That is to allow separate control of fan and light.  In that case, the "solo" black wire goes to one screw on the switch.  The other screw gets the (red or black) wire which was connected to the lamp in the ceiling.  Power one or the other, not both - who knows what the idle wire is touching!